# jQuery dropdown menu causes infinite loop after page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, drop-down-menu, navigation

I've attempted to create a navigation menu for a website which is a normal horizontal navigation bar on large screen widths, but becomes a jQuery dropdown when the window width is below 980px.

If the initial page load occurs with the window at less than 980px, the menu works as expected. However, if the window is resized at all, the mobile menu opens and closes multiple times before finally opening fully.

The website is http://host26.qnop.net/~fpsl/ - if you load it full-screen on a desktop computer, resize the window to a small width, and click the green button on the top right, you will see the behaviour of the menu.

My code is as follows:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      if($(window).width() < 980) {
        $("#mmenu").hide();
        $(".mtoggle").click(function() {
          $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
        });
      }
    });


    // check for window resize - show nav again for larger screens after hiding
    $(window).resize(function() {
     if($(window).width() < 980) {
        $("#mmenu").hide();
        $(".mtoggle").click(function() {
          $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
        });
      }
      if ($(window).width() > 980) {
                $('#mmenu').show();
            }
    });
```

I am very much a jQuery beginner and assume something I have done in the second section of the code is creating a loop somehow, but I don't know why or what I can do to correct it - I've tried changing the declarations to an if/else format but this makes no difference. I also don't understand why, if an accidental loop is occurring, the behaviour stops after a few opens and closes rather than continuing infinitely.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite loop is because you are binding the `$(".mtoggle").click(function ()` twice in your code at following places

- `if ($(window).width() < 980) {1`
- `$(window).resize(function () {`

when you re-size the `click` event is fired multiple times causing infinite loop.

so bind this code `$(".mtoggle").click(function ()` once in `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`

**js**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $(".mtoggle").click(function () {
         $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
     });
     if ($(window).width() < 980) {
         $("#mmenu").hide();
     }
 });

 $(window).resize(function () {
     if ($(window).width() < 980) {
         $("#mmenu").hide();
     }
     if ($(window).width() > 980) {
         $('#mmenu').show();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are resizing your window, the resize event triggers a lot of times, and this also  bind over and over again the click event.

When you click in the button, it triggers all the bindings at the same time to do the same thing and Boom! you have your crasy SlidingMenu

The solution for your problem is to create the click binding outside of the resize event (documentready), and also test the window width inside the click.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mtoggle").click(function () {
        //Test inside the click
        if ($(window).width() <= 980)
        {
            $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
        }
    });
    if ($(window).width() <= 980) {
        $("#mmenu").hide();
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 980) {
       $("#mmenu").hide();
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 980) {
       $('#mmenu').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not infinite loop, just too many times loop.

You duplicate `click` event, so any `resize` action would add once more `slideToggle` invoking.

You can proof that by clicking `maximize` button of browser,  and `slideToggle` just loop once, but if you resize the window by dragging browser edge, many many loops come up, while not infinite you'll see if patient enough. Because when dragging browser edge, `resize` event will be triggered any pixel.
So, from width of `1080px` to width of `980px`, there will be 99 more `slideToggle` invoking.